# Yii framework: how to pass arguments to grid's afterAjaxUpdate?

Tags: yii

How can I pass arguments to `CGridView` upon it's `afterAjaxUpdate` function? Currently, I manually set some values in HTML(in hiddent fields) and then they are read from grid's function `afterAjaxUpdate`.

This does work, but it doesn't sound professional. Any advice?

Here is an example of my "view" code:

```
<div style="width:<?php $asDialog==1?'700px':'800px' ?>;">
<?php
$appartmentUpdateLink = CJavaScript::encode($this->createUrl('appartment/update', array('id'=>'')));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'appartment-grid-milimeters-editable',
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search3(),
  'cssFile'=>Html::cssUrl('gridstyles'),
  'columns'=>array(
                array( //needed for keyboard arrow up/down binding scripts.
                    'id' => 'selectedIds',
                    'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                    'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array('tabindex'=>'-1'),
                ),
                array(
                    'name'=>'number',
                    'class' => 'phaEditColumn2',
                    'actionUrl' => array('appartment/setAttribute', 'attribute'=>'number'),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'15px'),
                ),
        array(
                    'name'=>'name',
                    'header'=>'Διαμ.',
                    'class' => 'phaEditColumn2',
                    'actionUrl' => array('appartment/setAttribute', 'attribute'=>'name'),
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'25px'),
                ),
  ),
  'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function(id, data) {
                var foundOnPage = false;
                var erroredIdsString = $("#recentIdDialogForError").text();
                var erroredIdsArray = erroredIdsString.split(",");
                var errorsLength = erroredIdsArray.length;
                //reset errored rows (red outline).
                $("#"+id).children(".items").children("tbody").find("input.select-on-check").closest("tr").css("outline", "0px");
                $("#"+id).children(".items").children("tbody").find("input.select-on-check").each(function () {
                    for(var i=0; i<errorsLength; i++){
                        if($(this).prop("value") == erroredIdsArray[i]){
                            $(this).closest("tr").css("outline", "1px solid red");
                        }
                    }
                    if($(this).prop("value") == $("#recentIdDialog").text()){ //return to page after normal create/update
                            foundOnPage = true;
                            $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
                            $(this).prop("checked", true);
                            $(".appartmentUpdateButton").prop("disabled", false);
                            $(".appartmentUpdateButton").parent().attr({
                                href: '. $appartmentUpdateLink .'+$("#recentIdDialog").text()+"?returnPage=2",
                            });
                    } //if
                else if($(this).prop("value") == $("#recentIdDialogForNext").text()){ //just updated record(s) inline at the editable grid
                    if(!$(this).closest("tr").is(":last-child")){
                        var nextTr = $(this).closest("tr").next();
                        foundOnPage = true;
                        $(nextTr).addClass("selected");
                        $(nextTr).find("input.select-on-check").prop("checked", true);
                        $(nextTr).find(".button-column a.update").trigger("click");
                        $(".appartmentUpdateButton").prop("disabled", false);
                        $(".appartmentUpdateButton").parent().attr({
                            href: '. $appartmentUpdateLink .'+$(nextTr).find("input.select-on-check").prop("value")+"?returnPage=2",
                        });
                    }else{ //it is the last child -- go add a new record!
                        $(".newButton").trigger("click");
                    }
                }//else if
                if(foundOnPage == false){
                    $(".appartmentUpdateButton").prop("disabled", true);
                    $(".appartmentUpdateButton").parent().removeAttr("href");
                }
?>
</div>
<div id='recentIdDialog' style='display:none'></div>
<div id='recentIdDialogForNext' style='display:none'></div>
<div id='recentIdDialogForNextSoft' style='display:none'></div>
<div id='recentIdDialogForError' style='display:none'></div>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::button('Διόρθωση', array('disabled'=>'disabled', 'id'=>'appartmentUpdateButton2', 'class'=>'appartmentUpdateButton', 'style'=>'width:120px')),array('appartment/update', 'id'=>''));?>
```

and one of the "view" scripts:

```
function sendData3(myUrl, dataObject){
    return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: myUrl,
                data: {myData: dataObject},
                success: function(answer){
                  var obj = $.parseJSON(answer);
                  var successArray = obj.success;
                  var failureArray = obj.failure;
                  var printableAnswer = "";
                  if(successArray.length > 0){
                    printableAnswer += obj.msgSuccess;
                    $("#recentIdDialog").html("");
                    $("#recentIdDialogForNext").html(successArray[successArray.length-1]);
                    $("#recentIdDialogForNextSoft").html("");
                    $("recentIdDialogForError").html("");
                  }
                  if(failureArray.length > 0){
                    printableAnswer += obj.msgFailure;
                    var errors = "";
                    $("recentIdDialogForError").html("");
                    $.each(obj.errors, function(key, val) {
                        errors += "<div class=\"flash-error\">" + val + "</div>";
                    });
                    printableAnswer += errors;
                    $("#recentIdDialog").html((obj.failure)[0]); //FIRST errored line of the grid remains selected.
                    $("#recentIdDialogForNext").html("");
                    $("#recentIdDialogForNextSoft").html("");
                    for(var j=0; j<failureArray.length; j++){
                        $("#recentIdDialogForError").append(failureArray[j] + ",");
                    }
                  }
                  $("#statusMsgDialog").html(printableAnswer);
                  $("#statusMsgDialog").show();
                  if(failureArray.length <= 0){
                    $("#statusMsgDialog").delay(7000).fadeOut("slow");
                  }
                },
        });
}
```

And the controller:

```
$dataObject = $_POST['myData'];
$item = $dataObject['item'];
$model=$this->loadModel($item);
$model->attributes = $dataObject;
$valid = $model->validate();
if($valid){
  if($model->save()){
    $answer = array(
      'status'=>'success',
      'id'=>$model->id,
      'msg'=>"<div class='flash-success'>Ajax - success [".($model->name?$model->name:$model->id)."].</div>");
    echo json_encode($answer);
    Yii::app()->end();
  }
}else{
  $error = CActiveForm::validate($model);
  $errorArray =  json_decode($error, true);
  $answer = array(
    'status'=>'error',
    'id'=>$model->id,
    'msg'=>"<div class='flash-error'>Ajax - error [".($model->name?$model->name:$model->id)."].</div>",
    'errors'=>$errorArray);
  echo json_encode($answer);
  Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code to explain further

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I have written some code to show what i mean. If you have time please have a look. Thanks in advance.